Mono switchIfEmpty with generics
Mono.switchIfEmpty expects a Mono<? extends T> as its parameter, where T is the type of the original Mono. How to use switchIfEmpty if actual and alternate are both ? extends T ?
Eg.
Mono<? extends Base> actualResponse = ...
Mono<? extends Base> alternateResponse = ...

actualResponse.switchIfEmpty(alternateResponse); //This wont work as switchIfEmpty will now expect Mono<? extends capture of ? extends Base>

I tried solving it couple of ways.

By making actualResponse and alernateResponse of type Mono<Base>
By casting actualResponse to Mono and then doing switchIfEmpty

((Mono<Base>)actualResponse).switchIfEmpty(alternateResponse);

Any better solutions or recommendations?

How about actualResponse.ofType(Base.class).switchIfEmpty(...)?

Don't misuse the mono tag as it's not related to Java.

This question is more about generics than Webflux. Do you understand them or do you need a response explaining why this will never be possible as long as signature of reactor.core.publisher.Mono#switchIfEmpty does not change?

@VincentC. I believe I understand them. I was looking for elegant solution than what I have proposed.
